# Linking from one page to another section of another web page

Tags: html, web, tags, anchor

I am currently coding a website in HTML 5. I am in the process of linking pages to certain parts of my webpage. For some reason the anchor point keeps taking me to the end of the page rather then the specified point?

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Show some code and specify which anchor takes to the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id = "main">
    One 
    <a href = "page2#main2">Go to main 2</a> 
</div>
```

Another Webpage : page2

```
<div id = "main2">
    Two

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the section you want to be

```
<div id="this-is-the-page">Hello World</div>
```

Just put this in your anchor tag

```
<a href="anotherpage.html#this-is-the-page">Link me there</a>
```